# keep data between fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm trying to keep data(PID) from fragmentscan to fragment maintenance using arguments,

but the data always null in my Log.d("tag", "PID SCAN: " + data);

whats wrong with my arguments?

this is my code

> ```
> public class FragmentScan extends Fragment {
>     TextView tvPid;
>     TextView txtName;
>     TextView txtPrice;
>     TextView txtDesc;
>     TextView txtSpec;
>
>     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
>
>
>     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
>
>     private static final String url_product_detials = "http://10.0.3.2/skripsi/get_product_details.php";
>     // JSON Node names
>     private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
>     private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
>     private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
>     private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
>     private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
>     private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
>     private static final String TAG_SPESIFICATION = "spesification";
>     // Progress Dialog
>     private static final String PID_KEY = "tvPid";
>     private static final String NAME_KEY = "tvName";
>     private static final String PRICE_KEY = "tvPrice";
>     private static final String DESCRIPTION_KEY = "tvDesc";
>     private static final String SPESIFICATION_KEY = "tvSpec";
>
>     private String mPid=null;
>     private String mName=null;
>     private String mPrice=null;
>     private String mDesc=null;
>     private String mSpec=null;
>
>     Button Btngetdata;
>     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>
>     @Override
>     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         Log.d("ZZZ", "ada di oncreateView");
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_four, container, false);
>         tvPid = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvPid);
>         txtName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
>         txtPrice = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
>         txtDesc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
>         txtSpec = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpec);
>         Btngetdata = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.getdata);
>         Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View view) {
>                 Fragment fragment = new FragmentMaintenance();
>                 Bundle data = new Bundle();
>                 data.putString("pid", mPid);
>                 fragment.setArguments(data);
>                 FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
>                 Log.d("tag", "PID SCAN: " + data);
>                 frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
>                         .commit();
>             }
>         });
>
>         Button scanBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
>         //in some trigger function e.g. button press within your code you should add:
>         scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>                 try {
>                     Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
>                     intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
>                     startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
>
>                 } catch (Exception e) {
>                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>         if (savedInstanceState != null) {
>             Log.d("ZZZ", "ada di di dlm if saved");
>
>             mPid = savedInstanceState.getString(PID_KEY);
>             mName = savedInstanceState.getString(NAME_KEY);
>             mPrice = savedInstanceState.getString(PRICE_KEY);
>             mDesc = savedInstanceState.getString(DESCRIPTION_KEY);
>             mSpec = savedInstanceState.getString(SPESIFICATION_KEY);
>             tvPid.setText(mPid);
>             txtName.setText(mName);
>             txtPrice.setText(mPrice);
>             txtDesc.setText(mDesc);
>             txtSpec.setText(mSpec);
>         }
>         return rootView;
>     }
>
>
>     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
>         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
>         Log.d("ZZZ", "Ada di mainactivity");
>         if (requestCode == 0) {
>             TextView pid = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvPid);
>
>             if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
>                 pid.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
>                 new GetProductDetails(getActivity()).execute(pid.getText().toString());
>             } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
>                 pid.setText("Scan cancelled.");
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
>
>         /**
>          * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
>          */
>         private Context mContext;
>
>         public GetProductDetails(Context context) {
>             mContext = context;
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onPreExecute() {
>             super.onPreExecute();
>             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
>             pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
>             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>             pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>             pDialog.show();
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Getting product details in background thread
>          */
>         protected String[] doInBackground(String... string) {
>
>             // Check for success tag
>             int success;
>             try {
>                 // Building Parameters
>                 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>                 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", string[0]));
>                 // getting product details by making HTTP request
>                 // Note that product details url will use GET request
>                 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
>                         url_product_detials, "GET", params);
>                 Log.d("ZZZ", json.toString());
>
>                 success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>                 if (success == 1) {
>                     // successfully received product details
>                     JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array
>
>                     // get first product object from JSON Array
>                     JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
>
>                     // product with this pid found
>                     // Edit Text
>                     String[] result = {Integer.toString(success), product.getString(TAG_NAME), >                         product.getString(TAG_PRICE),
>                     product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION),
>                     product.getString(TAG_SPESIFICATION)};
>
> //                    // display product data in EditText
> //                    txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
> //                    txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
> //                    txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
>
>                     Log.d("ZZZ", result[0]);
>                     return result;
>                 } else {
>                     Log.d("ZZZ", Integer.toString(success));
>                     String[] result = {Integer.toString(success)};
>                     return result;
>                 }
>             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>                 return null;
>             }
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
>          * *
>          */
>         protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {
>             // dismiss the dialog once got all details
>             pDialog.dismiss();
>
>             if (results[0] != null) {
>                 Log.d("ZZZ", "SUCCESS" + results[0]);
>                 if (results[0].matches("1")) {
>                     Log.d("ZZZ", "SUCCESS " + results[0]);
>                     TextView name = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvName);
>                     name.setText(results[1]);
>                     TextView price = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
>                     price.setText(results[2]);
>                     TextView desc = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
>                     desc.setText(results[3]);
>                     TextView spec = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvSpec);
>                     spec.setText(results[4]);
>                 } else if (results[0].matches("-1")) {
>                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                 } else{
>                     Log.d("ZZZ", "UNKNOWN ERROR");
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         // Save state information with a collection of key-value pairs
>         // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
>         super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
>         savedInstanceState.putString(PID_KEY, tvPid.getText().toString());
>         savedInstanceState.putString(NAME_KEY, txtName.getText().toString());
>         savedInstanceState.putString(PRICE_KEY, txtPrice.getText().toString());
>         savedInstanceState.putString(DESCRIPTION_KEY, txtDesc.getText().toString());
>         savedInstanceState.putString(SPESIFICATION_KEY, txtSpec.getText().toString());
>     }
> }
> ```

This my activity

> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
> private ListView mDrawerList;
> private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
>
> private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
> private CharSequence mTitle;
> CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;
> SharedPreferences preferences;
> String pref;
> List<DrawerItem> dataList;
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     preferences = this.getSharedPreferences(Config.PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
>     pref = preferences.getString(Config.SESSION,null);
>     // Initializing
>     dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
>     mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
>     mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
>     mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
>
>     mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
>             GravityCompat.START);
>
>     // Add Drawer Item to dataList
>     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Scanner", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
>     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Schedule", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
>     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Games", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
>     dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Logout", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
>
>
>     adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
>             dataList);
>
>     mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
>
>     mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
>
>     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
>     getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
>
>     mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
>             R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
>             R.string.drawer_close) {
>         public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
>             getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
>             invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
>             // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
>         }
>
>         public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
>             getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
>             invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
>             // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
>         }
>     };
>
>     mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
>
>     if (savedInstanceState == null) {
>         SelectItem(0);
>     }
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
> public void SelectItem(int possition) {
>
>     Fragment fragment = null;
>     Bundle args = new Bundle();
>     switch (possition) {
>         case 0:
>             fragment = new FragmentScan();
>             break;
>         case 1:
>             fragment = new FragmentSchedule();
>
>             break;
>         case 2:
>             fragment = new FragmentThree();
>             args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
>                     .getItemName());
>             args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
>                     .getImgResID());
>             break;
>         case 3:
>             logout();
>             Intent in = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
>             startActivity(in);
>             finish();
>             return;
>
>         default:
>             break;
>     }
>
>     fragment.setArguments(args);
>     FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
>     frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
>             .commit();
>
>     mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
>     setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
>     mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
>
> }
>
> @Override
> public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
>     mTitle = title;
>     getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
>     mDrawerToggle.syncState();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
>     super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
>     // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
>     mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
>     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
>     if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     return false;
> }
>
> private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
>         ListView.OnItemClickListener {
>     @Override
>     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
>                             long id) {
>         SelectItem(position);
>
>     }
> }
> //In the same activity you’ll need the following to retrieve the results:
> private void logout(){
>     //TODO delete cookie from db
>
>     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
>     editor.remove(Config.SESSION);
>     editor.remove(Config.USERNAME);
>     editor.commit();
> }
> ```

i hope someone can help me to solving this,
thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's supposed to be not null, perhaps you just didn't retrieve the value properly.

In your logging code, you used:

```
Log.d("tag", "PID SCAN: " + data);
```

but actually you stored the pid using:

```
data.putString("pid", mPid);
```

which means, you should use key `pid` to get the value from the bundle, like:

```
Log.d("tag", "PID SCAN: " + data.getString("pid"));
```

**EDIT:**

If it is a process ID you are trying to get, try to look at `android.os.Process.myPid();`

If `pid` is your own pre-defined variable (containing something else),
then you need to pass it when you create the fragment like the following:

```
fragment = new FragmentScan();
args.putString("pid", YOUR_TV_PID_VALUE);
```

and from the other side (`FragmentScan`), you can use `getArguments()` to get the `Bundle`, and from there, just use `getString("pid")`.

**UPDATE:**

After reading your code more, it seems you got the cycle a little bit tangled.
but one quick suggestion is: why don't you try it like the following

```
data.putString("pid", tvPid.getText());
```

In you original code, your `pid` in `savedInstanceState` supposed to be exist after you perform click on `scanBtn`, finish/cancel the scanning. But I think your code flow is a little bit tangled.
**Read** [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) that `onSaveInstanceState` is called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity *before being killed*.
=> That means, before you open another intent (performed by `scanBtn`), `onSaveInstanceState` is called and storing empty value of the `tvPid`. And when the main intent is resumed, it gets that bundle which contains empty string of `pid`. But it should be `""`, not null.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Anyway, my answer seems no help. I delete it.

Comment: i had change my log d to be like data.putString("pid", mPid);
but i have same respons.. "null"

Comment: yes, I saw that, and have you tried `Log.d("tag", "PID SCAN: " + data.getString("pid"));`?

Comment: if it still does, then you should show another snippet that called this `FragmentScan`

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 i had same response "null"

Comment: could you show us the code which instantiated this `FragmentScan`?

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 you mean my activity? or my fragment maintenance?

Comment: I think we need your activity. `FragmentMaintenance` is called by `FragmentScan`, not the one who calls it.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 i have attach my activity yohanes.. thanks for helping me

Comment: I'm using drawer for the menu

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 thank you very much for your help.. now the pid can use in other fragment.. 
do you have an suggestion structure for my tangled code?

Comment: good to hear that. in short, you want to pass your value through that `savedInstanceState` bundle but it doesn't work due to the code-execution-flow according to the life-cycle. that's why I suggested to just get the value from the `textview` directly. If you still want to try, you may try to find a way to attach that `pid` value to the bundle of the paused main intent –not the scanning intent (com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN)– IN your `onActivityResult`. I haven't tried it, though.